# Why the Flask app is still running its thread when it breaks out of its while loop?

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I am writing a Flask app runs on `start=true` and stops at `start=false`. From the log, I can see that the while loop stops when `is_set()` returns False, but right after the app starts running again. I tried different methods but none of them seems to work so far. Could someone shed some light on this?

```py
@app.route('/')
def index():
    status = request.args.get('start', default=False, type=str)
    flag = threading.Event()
    
    if status == 'true':
        flag.set()
    else:
        flag.clear()
  
    t = threading.Thread(target=run, args=(flag,))
    t.start()
    t.join()

    return status

def run(flag):
    while flag.is_set() == True:
        print('running')
        time.sleep(1)
    print('done')
```

Here is the printed log:

```
running
running
running
done
127.0.0.1 - - [27/Aug/2021 20:52:46] "GET /?start=false HTTP/1.1" 200 -
running
running
running
```

Answer (score 0):

You create a new thread and a new instance of `flag` every time the endpoint is hit. This means that the `flag` that is cleared for a subsequent request will not affect that of the previous request.

```
running  #request 1
running  #request 1
running  #request 1
done     #request 2
127.0.0.1 - - [27/Aug/2021 20:52:46] "GET /?start=false HTTP/1.1" 200 -   #request 2
running  #request 1
running  #request 1
running  #request 1
```

If you want to control the thread with a http request, the creation of the thread and flag should be outside the request handler.

```
t = threading.Thread(target=run, args=(flag,))
t.start()
flag = threading.Event()

@app.route('/')
def index():
    status = request.args.get('start', default=False, type=str)
    
    if status == 'true':
        flag.set()
        if !t.is_alive():
            t = threading.Thread(target=run, args=(flag,))
            t.start()
    else:
        flag.clear()
    return status

def run(flag):
    while flag.is_set() == True:
        print('running')
        time.sleep(1)
    print('done')
```

Comment: I appreciate your comment. I tried three different methods based on your suggestion. 1) Save thread both Thread and Event object in Flask's g - didn't work as they are not sharable between requests. 2) Save them in a session object. 3) Create a class that handles the initiation and execution of threading. This works partially. It does not run once the initial thread stops. Do you mind providing some code examples on this?

Comment: @DPark I had to make the assumption that if the initial thread stops, the next start=true request will start another thread.